# How to render an array inside an array object with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

How do i get the recipeName using .map() in React?

Below is my dummy data for the recipe.

```
const recipe = [
  {
    category: 'Keto',
    name: 'Chicken Bistek',
    calories: '500',
    description: '',
    recipes: [
      {
        recipeName: 'Chicken',
        recipeSize: '3 lbs',
      },
      {
        recipeName: 'Garlic',
        recipeSize: '4 cloves',
      },
      {
        recipeName: 'Onion',
        recipeSize: '1 whole',
      },
      {
        recipeName: 'Soy Sauce',
        recipeSize: '1/4 cup',
      },
      {
        recipeName: 'Coconut Oil',
        recipeSize: '1 tbsp',
      },
      {
        recipeName: 'Water',
        recipeSize: '1 cup',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I've tried this code below but it wont display the recipes array. It displays the name, category. But recipe.recipeName and recipe.recipeSize wont display in a tag.

```
const DietList = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.diets.map((diet) => (
        <div key={diet.name}>
          <a>{diet.name}</a>
          <a>{diet.category}</a>
          {diet.recipes.map((recipe) => (
            <a key={recipe.recipeName}>{recipe.recipeSize}</a>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Works as expected for me [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-matsumoto-jkkbew?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Works fine. You need to display the recipeName as well.   <a>{recipe.recipeSize}</a> and <a>{recipe.recipeName}</a>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, just you are not displaying recipeName

```
<>
   {props.diets.map((diet) => (
          <div key={diet.name}>
            <a>{diet.name}</a>
            <a>{diet.category}</a>
            <span>
              {diet.recipes.map((recipe) => (
// i added span so that we can add multiple tags
                <span key={recipe.recipeName}> 

                  <a>{recipe.recipeSize}</a>
                  <a>{recipe.recipeName}</a> 
                </span>
              ))}
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, I am making use of your dummy data:

```
{
       recipe.map((item, index) => {
         return (
           <div key={index}>
               <span>{item.category}</span>
               <br />
               <span>{item.name}</span>
               <div>
                {
                  item.recipes.map((r, index) => {
                    return (
                      <>
                        <span key={index} >{r.recipeName}: {r.recipeSize}</span><br />
                      </>
                    )
                  })
                }
               </div>
           </div>
         )
       })
     }
```

I am not sure why you are using `a` tag. Unless, you are going to link it with a href tag.

But I have used the `return` in the map, and it's working fine. Hope, it will work for you too.